# Is it possible to relabel a video format in a gstreamer pipeline?

Tags: gstreamer

What I'm trying to do boils down to this:  We have video data in one format, let's say RGBx, but due to bugs/quirks we need to make the next element think it's another format, let's say v210.

The bits are correct; we don't want to use a videoconvert. We need to lie to the next element, telling it "here's your v210 data".

In a way, what I'm looking for is a gstreamer equivalent of C++'s reinterpret_cast, where the bits stay the same but are thought of as something different.

Is this possible?

Comment: I have found gstreamer's capsetter element, maybe that's what I want...